# Access instance methods in a component wrapped in a Higher Order Component - React.js

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, jasmine

I am writing some tests for my React component:

```
let DebugElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Debug />);
console.log(DebugElement)
spyOn(DebugElement, 'fetchAndSelect');
```

However, it says that `fetchAndSelect` doesn't exist. Which is true.

I wrap my component like so:

```
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';

const Debug = React.createClass({
     fetchAndSelect() {}
});

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Debug);
```

If you look at the screenshot below, you can see that I can access my component methods inside `refs.child`. Is this the right way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wrapped component instance is provided via `getDecoratedComponentInstance()`:

```
let tree = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Debug />);
let DebugElement = tree.getDecoratedComponentInstance();
console.log(DebugElement);
spyOn(DebugElement, 'fetchAndSelect');
```

You can also access the original, non-wrapped component *type* via `DecoratedComponent` on the wrapped component type, and you can use `TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType` or other methods to find the component:

```
let tree = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Debug />);
let DebugElement = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(
  tree, Debug.DecoratedComponent
);
console.log(DebugElement)
spyOn(DebugElement, 'fetchAndSelect');
```

Take a look at the [Testing docs](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-testing.html) for more information.